# Iterating over QuranGlobal JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, object, response

I have a difficulty iterating over the JSON response from QuranGlobal.com the response is coming too nested with a lot of objects and documentations are very complicated specially it's my first app so I am not that much expert

I did try a lot of things and nothing helps while other apis is not matching what in my mind
one more question : after iterating how to dsiplay on the screen to be like pages not lists shall I use FaltList or something else

if anybody can give me help

Thank you in advance

```
{
    "quran": {
        "quran-simple": {
            "6222": {
                "id": 6222,
                "surah": 112,
                "ayah": 1,
                "verse": " قُلْ هُوَ اللَّهُ أَحَدٌ"
            },
            "6223": {
                "id": 6223,
                "surah": 112,
                "ayah": 2,
                "verse": "اللَّهُ الصَّمَدُ"
            },
            "6224": {
                "id": 6224,
                "surah": 112,
                "ayah": 3,
                "verse": "لَمْ يَلِدْ وَلَمْ يُولَدْ"
            },
            "6225": {
                "id": 6225,
                "surah": 112,
                "ayah": 4,
                "verse": "وَلَمْ يَكُنْ لَهُ كُفُوًا أَحَدٌ"
            },
            "6226": {
                "id": 6226,
                "surah": 113,
                "ayah": 1,
                "verse": " قُلْ أَعُوذُ بِرَبِّ الْفَلَقِ"
            },
            "6227": {
                "id": 6227,
                "surah": 113,
                "ayah": 2,
                "verse": "مِنْ شَرِّ مَا خَلَقَ"
            },
            "6228": {
                "id": 6228,
                "surah": 113,
                "ayah": 3,
                "verse": "وَمِنْ شَرِّ غَاسِقٍ إِذَا وَقَبَ"
            },
            "6229": {
                "id": 6229,
                "surah": 113,
                "ayah": 4,
                "verse": "وَمِنْ شَرِّ النَّفَّاثَاتِ فِي الْعُقَدِ"
            },
            "6230": {
                "id": 6230,
                "surah": 113,
                "ayah": 5,
                "verse": "وَمِنْ شَرِّ حَاسِدٍ إِذَا حَسَدَ"
            },
            "6231": {
                "id": 6231,
                "surah": 114,
                "ayah": 1,
                "verse": " قُلْ أَعُوذُ بِرَبِّ النَّاسِ"
            },
            "6232": {
                "id": 6232,
                "surah": 114,
                "ayah": 2,
                "verse": "مَلِكِ النَّاسِ"
            },
            "6233": {
                "id": 6233,
                "surah": 114,
                "ayah": 3,
                "verse": "إِلَٰهِ النَّاسِ"
            },
            "6234": {
                "id": 6234,
                "surah": 114,
                "ayah": 4,
                "verse": "مِنْ شَرِّ الْوَسْوَاسِ الْخَنَّاسِ"
            },
            "6235": {
                "id": 6235,
                "surah": 114,
                "ayah": 5,
                "verse": "الَّذِي يُوَسْوِسُ فِي صُدُورِ النَّاسِ"
            },
            "6236": {
                "id": 6236,
                "surah": 114,
                "ayah": 6,
                "verse": "مِنَ الْجِنَّةِ وَالنَّاسِ"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
const firstAyah = 6222, lastAyah = 6236
const resp = `your json response`
for(let i = firstAyah, i <= lastAyah; i++)
    console.log(`Surah: ${resp.quran['quran-simple'][i].surah} Ayah number: ${resp.quran.['quran-simple'][i].ayah}, Ayah: ${resp.quran.['quran-simple'][i].verse}`)
```

If you encounter any problem, please let me know

Comment: Thank you dear @Syed Mishar Newaz but how to get firstAyah and lastAyah without knowing the number before. I mean not always firstAyah will be 6222 or lastAyah will be 6236

Comment: and then please if you have an advice how to display them to be shown like holy Quran book to come Ayat side by side . I did try a lot of things but nothing works....

Comment: All right, can you provide me the link of the api doc? Also, do you have to particularly use this API? Or, can I suggest you another easier one?

Comment: http://api.alquran.cloud/v1/page/600/quran-uthmani
This is the api I am using now and it works with me and feel it's easier ...

Comment: https://alquran.cloud/api is the api which I was about to suggest 

Comment: their documentation is awesome. alright, keep doing good work. may Allah put barakah in your project

Comment: Yes thank you dear. Although I am facing some challenges and don't know if I could contact you privately 

Comment: @Sayed Mishar Newaz could you please take a look ther ? :)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61645516/how-to-change-params-value-passed-to-axios-route-to-change-data-react-native/61645837#61645837